# Flask - NOT NULL constraint failed. Can't delete user with it's own ID?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sql-delete

Whenever I try to db.session.delete(user) and commit it, I get a NO NULL CONSTRAINT Error.

The error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.user_id
    [SQL: UPDATE post SET user_id=? WHERE post.id = ?]
    [parameters: (None, 2)]
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

@users.route('/delete/<string:id>')
def delete_account(id):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, 
default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Since User and Post are related and a User is the author of a Post, I'm guessing your Post model has a foreign key to User and you have set it `null=False`. The default cascading behaviour of `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship` tries to set the foreign key to NULL, when a User is deleted.

Comment: Ahh I see, Could I use like delete cascade so when I delete the user all of its related posts are deleted aswell?

Comment: That's one option. All in all https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html is a good read. It covers the ORM relationship cascades and how they compare to and work together with the SQL foreign key cascades.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!